# MVC Override OnException Error: No suitable method found to override

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

I'm trying to override OnException in Global.asax to handle error and writing log. I'm not sure which part is wrong, I keep on getting the error "MyApp.MvcApplication.OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext)': no suitable method found to override" whenever I rebuild my solution.

this is the code I have in Application_Start()

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();         
    }
```

And this is the code I have in OnException()

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Exception ex = context.Exception;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.Message) ||
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.Source.ToString()) ||
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.StackTrace))
        {                

            WriteLog(ex.Message.ToString(), ex.StackTrace.ToString(), ex.Source.ToString(), "0");

            context.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = String.Format("~/ErrorPage/ErrorPage?message={0}&stack={1}&source={2}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ex.Message), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ex.StackTrace), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ex.Source))
            };
        }

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```

The WriteLog() function is tested working in other application, I don't think there's any problem in it and I even tried:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext context) {
    Exception ex = context.Exception;

    context.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Shared/Error.cshtml";
            };
    context.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

But nothing work. The error just remain there.

How could such problem occur and how do I fix it? I read many tutorial about this, I don't think I'm spelling OnException() wrongly.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any `OnException` inside `Global.asax`

You have two ways:

Create your own `HandleErrorAttribute` and register in `FilterConfig.cs`

```
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

FilterConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleExceptionsAttribute());
    (...)
}
```

Or, if you have a `BaseController` where all controllers are inherited from, override the `OnException` method.

PS: I would go for the filter one.

Comment: After so many days of reading and struggles, I didn't find any resources telling me OnException is not exist within Global.asax, part of it's of course my weak foundation in OOP. Really thankful for this useful information, now the error is no more and I'm able to override OnException for my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method OnException in the global asax, that method belongs to the controllers.to handle errors in the global asax use the method **Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)**